# Реализация класса-таблицы

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь сделать класс, который будет описывать некую таблицу в БД. Никак не могу придумать как его описать наилучшим образом. Сейчас есть что-то такое:

```
class IColumn{
public:
    virtual const QString& name() const = 0;
    virtual const QString& type() const = 0;
    virtual const QString& settings() const = 0;
    virtual ~IColumn(){}
};

class IRow{
public:
    virtual QString value(int index) const = 0;
    virtual int size() const = 0;
    virtual ~IRow(){}
};

class ITable{
public:
    virtual int rowCount() const = 0;
    virtual int columnCount() const = 0;
    virtual const IRow& row(int index) const = 0;
    virtual const IColumn& column(int index) const = 0;
    virtual const QString& name() const = 0;
    virtual const QString& settings() const = 0;
    virtual ~ITable(){}
};
```

Конкретная таблица должна хранить набор конкретных столбцов и конкретных строк:

```
class Table : public ITable{
    class Row : public IRow{
        //...
    };
    class Column : public IColumn{
        //...
    };
    QVector<Row> _rows;
    QVector<Column> _columns;
    //...
};
```

В этой организации меня смущает то, что реализация `Row` и количество объектов в векторе `_columns` тесно связаны, но в коде это никак не отражено. Я могу добавить новый столбец в `_columns`, но при этом забыть изменить реализацию `Row` и все нормально скомпилируется.

Еще некрасиво смотрится то, что `ITable::columnCount` и `IRow::size` вообще-то должны возвращать одно и то же значение. Но если избавится от одного из этих методов, то невозможно будет узнать сколько в пустой таблице строк или сколько в произвольной строке столбцов.

Может кто-нибудь может предложить более естественную реализацию таблицы?

Answer (score 2):

В таблице строки и колонки, по идее, не должны хранить информацию. Они всего лишь средство навигации. Данные же должны храниться в иной сущности, называемой ячейка.

Таблица - это специализация матрицы, отличающейся от последней лишь наличием горизонтальных и вертикальных заголовков, поэтому реализацию кода предлагаю начать именно с матрицы.

```
template<class T>
class Matrix {
    public:
        explicit Matrix() : _rows(0), _cols(0) {}

        explicit Matrix(int rows, int cols)
            : _rows(rows), _cols(cols), _cells(rows*cols) {}

        virtual ~Matrix() {}

        int rows() const {return _rows;}
        int cols() const {return _cols;}

        void insertRows(int row, int cnt) {
            if(_rows >= row && row >= 0 && cnt > 0) {
                if(_cols == 0) _cols = 1;
                _cells.insert(_cols * row, _cols * cnt, T());
                _rows += cnt;
            }
        }

        void removeRows(int row, int cnt) {
            if(_rows >= (row+cnt) && row >= 0 && cnt > 0) {
                _cells.remove(_cols * row, _cols * cnt);
                _rows -= cnt; if(_rows == 0) _cols = 0;
            }
        }

        void insertCols(int col, int cnt) {
            if(_cols >= col && col >= 0 && cnt > 0) {
                if(_rows == 0) _rows = 1;
                for(int row = 0; row < _rows; ++row)
                    _cells.insert(pos(row,col)+(row*cnt), cnt, T());

                _cols += cnt;
            }
        }

        void removeCols(int col, int cnt) {
            if(_cols >= (col+cnt) && col >= 0 && cnt > 0) {
                for(int row = 0; row < _rows; ++row)
                    _cells.remove(pos(row,col)-(row*cnt), cnt);

                _cols -= cnt; if(_cols == 0) _rows = 0;
            }
        }

        const T &data(int row, int col) const {
            return _cells[pos(row,col)];
        }

        T &data(int row, int col) {
            return _cells[pos(row,col)];
        }

        void clear() {_rows = 0; _cols = 0; _cells.clear();}

    private:
        int _rows, _cols;

        QVector<T> _cells;

        int pos(int row, int col) const {
            return _cols * row + col;
        }
};
```

Кто-то предпочитает хранить ячейки в двумерном массиве, я же привёл вариант с использованием обычного вектора. Несмотря на большую сложность при добавлении/удалении строк/столбцов по сравнению с двумерным вариантом, этот не менее интересен.

Поскольку таблица, как уже было заявлено, является специализацией матрицы, то соответствующий класс может быть легко унаследован от предыдущего с добавлением функционала для заголовков.

```
template<class T>
class Table : public Matrix<T> {
    public:
        explicit Table() : Matrix<T>(1,1) {}

        explicit Table(int rows, int cols)
            : Matrix<T>(rows+1,cols+1) {}

        virtual ~Table() {}

        int rows() const {return Matrix<T>::rows()-1;}
        int cols() const {return Matrix<T>::cols()-1;}

        void insertRows(int row, int cnt) {
            Matrix<T>::insertRows(row+1, cnt);
        }

        void removeRows(int row, int cnt) {
            Matrix<T>::removeRows(row+1, cnt);
        }

        void insertCols(int col, int cnt) {
            Matrix<T>::insertCols(col+1, cnt);
        }

        void removeCols(int col, int cnt) {
            Matrix<T>::removeCols(col+1, cnt);
        }

        const T &headerRowData(int row) const {
            return Matrix<T>::data(row+1, 0);
        }

        T &headerRowData(int row) {
            return Matrix<T>::data(row+1, 0);
        }

        const T &headerColData(int col) const {
            return Matrix<T>::data(0, col+1);
        }

        T &headerColData(int col) {
            return Matrix<T>::data(0, col+1);
        }

        const T &data(int row, int col) const {
            return AMatrix<T>::data(row+1, col+1);
        }

        T &data(int row, int col) {
            return Matrix<T>::data(row+1, col+1);
        }
};
```

Как хорошо заметно, класс таблицы не занимается ничем иным, кроме как корректировкой индексов строк и колонок при обращении к методам матрицы с тем, чтобы иметь возможность хранить информацию о заголовках в первой её строке и в первой её колонке.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Как я понял у вас матрица содержит элементы одного типа. А у меня там мешанина из строк, интов и булов. Можно, конечно, хранить все в `QVariant`, но я искренне верю что можно обойтись без этого

Comment: Кстати, можно считать что количество столбцов и их типы известны заранее и никогда не меняются. Поэтому над их удалением/добавлением можно не заморачиваться.

Comment: Если Вы хотите использовать свой класс таблицы совместно с моделями Qt, то у последних `QVariant` фактически стандарт. Что касаемо поддержки изменения кол-ва строк и столбцов, то её легко убрать из класса.

Comment: По поводу поддержки вставки и получения данных определённого типа (строка, число и т.п.) без `QVariant`... Вам ведь всё равно понадобится какой-то класс-контейнер на шаблонах, который будет хранить произвольный тип (плюс, наверное к этому ещё и классы интерфейсов понадобятся). Но по сути, тот же "вариант". Мне просто любопытно, по какой причине Вы отказываетесь от использования `QVariant`?

Comment: Я думаю не потребуется. Смотрите какая история. Сейчас есть набор таблиц который задает конфигурацию приложения. Нужно написать графический редактор для них. Само приложение будет оперировать конкретными классами(не через интерфейсы). Интерфейсы нужны для того, чтобы потом эти классы экспортировать в sql-таблицы.

Comment: То есть по сути будет какой-то метод типа `QString toSql(const ITable &table)`, который будет возвращать скрипт, создающий таблицу в БД. А всё остальное приложение будет оперировать строками интами и булами. Ну это очень грубое приближение, конечно. Но суть передает

Comment: Понял Вас. А я вот наоборот ищу решение максимально возможной универсализации, призванной сократить кол-во файлов. Если проект разрастается, индивидуальный подход к каждой отдельной таблице с отдельным модулем становится проблемой при появлении необходимости внесения общих, но учитывающих индивидуальные особенности изменений. Впрочем, специфика, может, такая.